# A word that means this time next week

Tags: single-word-requests

In many Asian cultures there is a word that means 8 days from now i.e. Monday to Monday, is there such a word in English. The only thing I can find is the phrase "This time next week" referring to the day rather than the time.

Comment: We call that seven days from now in English, just like we call a fortnight hence fourteen days not fifteen days from now. In Iberian cultures they count the way you do, but not in English ones, so for example a *quincena* (from their word for fifteen) is a fortnight in Spanish. They'll say "I'll see you in eight days" or "I'll see you in fifteen days" but we'll say "I'll see you in a week/seven days" or "I'll see you in a fortnight/fourteen days" but the time span and meaning is in all cases the same despite being represented differently in figures by the two different cultures.

Comment: We may also call it 'a week today'.

Comment: 1. What @tchrist said (consider making it an answer). 2. Another expression for this is *"a week from now"*.

Comment: Do you mean _at this same hour_ in a week, or is it just the same day of the week but next week?

Comment: If today is Monday and eight days from now is also Monday, then is one day from now today?  What does “see you a year from now” mean?

Comment: Using either 8 or 7 to mean a week: varies by language, and perhaps by circumstance.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=vaccine&oq=&aqs=chrome.0.69i59i450l8.1277561003j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

**week**, Phrases P2a(b)

> (b) Following a specified day, as Monday week, this day week, tomorrow
> week, yesterday week, etc.: seven days before or after the day
> specified. Cf. earlier sennight n.
>
> 1680   E. Hookes Due Order Law & Justice 42   Mary Duncon, to have
> been called into the Court of Sessions this day week.
>
> 1889   ‘J. S. Winter’ Mrs. Bob i   Let us say Thursday week, dear—This
> is Saturday, so it is quite enough notice to give. 1957   F. O'Connor
> Let. 19 May (1979) 220   Last Friday week I stood in a receiving line
> with your brother and sister-in-law for a good hour.
>
> 1990   Guardian 25 Sept. 15/1   Reilly..is due to announce his..squad
> tomorrow week.
>
> 2004   D. Peace GB 84 80   However, Monday week, there will also be a
> Union family rally in the town

Thus, the phrase the OP is looking for would be **today week**

As for **sennight**, according to quotes in the [OED, sennight](https://www.google.com/search?q=vaccine&oq=&aqs=chrome.0.69i59i450l8.1277561003j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), one of its uses is the same as that of **week**, as described above.

> My birthday is last Sunday sennight  (made up)

**But sennight is so British English and so obscure that it is best ignored except by language aficianados.**

Comment: I'm not sure untravelled Americans would understand that usage.

Comment: 'Let's meet again today week' or 'The assignment is due today week' don't sound at all natural to me. Adding a preposition doesn't work for me either. 'Let's meet again same day next week' or 'The assignment is due _in one_ week' have the minimal additions to make them work for me.

Comment: @Mitch It is more natural for Brits, and unnatural for Americans.  Whether this is useful for the OP depends on how often he talks to Brits and/or anglophiles.

Comment: Yes! "See you Monday week" (on the Monday after next Monday).  "The meeting is for Wednesday week" (on the Wednesday after next Wednesday).  "Today/tomorrow week" - not for me either @Mitch, though I'd understand it.  It works only when connected to the named day.

Comment: @tchrist Not just untravelled Americans. This somewhat travelled British person has never heard "sennight" and only ever seen it on EL&U. I'd say "a week today" and stand a chance if being understood and not being regarded as a pretentious berk.

Comment: @BoldBen It’s *Tuesday week* that confuses the untravelled American, not *sennight*, which is surely as unknown as  the seven-day *hebdomad*  is to most anyone.  Me, I always figured that *sennight* was the Roman version of the classic Greek [*hen night*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hen_night), kinda like how *septagon* with S is merely the Latin version of Greek *heptagon* (ie, *ἑπτάγωνον*) with H, all because of the recurring S⇔H swap between those two languages. :)

Comment: @tchrist How about the British working class "A week o' Monday" which, in many working class accents sounds like "A Wicker Monday" and could make you think it was something made out of basketwork!

Comment: "sennight" is just an archaic word for a week, from "seven nights". It doesn't specifically mean "one week from now" any more than "week" does (at least that's based on the dictionaries I consulted, it's certainly not a word anyone would use today).

Comment: @Stuart  That is why the last sentence of my answer says it should be ignored by all except a few.